# How to purchase Japan train tickets online and also Japan scenic itinerary?

Tags: japan, japan-rail

I will be travelling to Japan next month for 10 days and I need to ask 2 questions here:

1 Is there any official Japanese website to buy train ticket online?

2 What would be the best scenic itinerary starting from Tokyo and ending in Osaka 
  or Tokyo for 10 days?

Also my ideal itinerary would be train journey only.

Comment: I'd edit out your second question as recommendations are off-topic here

Comment: While I dont want to encourage off topic answers, I suggest you look into Hakone, Izu peninsula and Nara. They should provide a nice start.

Comment: First 3 answers look precise , would be unfair to accept just1

Answer (score 10):

**For travelling outside eastern Japan, there is no way to buy or reserve tickets from abroad.** 
(Unless you can read Japanese)

For eastern Japan, you can reserve train tickets on the JR EAST network via their website [(found here)](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/).

NOTE: JR EAST only covers the following part of Japan:
[image: JR East map]

Even if you can't reserve a train ticket in advance, you will find that unless you are travelling during one of the three busy periods, you will have no trouble finding a seat without reserving it in advance. Simply show up to the counter, buy a ticket (or show your JR pass) and the attendant will hand you a seat reservation.

The busy periods include:

- Golden Week: usually around 28 April to 7 May
- Obon: Usually 10 August to 20 August
- Shogatsu: 28 December to 4 January

---

As blackbird57 and Federico mentioned, if you plan on travelling by rail, a JR pass can be extremely worth it. Use websites like [Hyperdia](http://www.hyperdia.com/en/) to get a rough estimate of the total cost of your train tickets and compare that to the cost of a JR pass, you could save lots of money.

[Source](http://www.insidekyoto.com/2012/01/reserving-japanese-train-tickets-from.html)

Comment: good answer actually i was more interested in Tokyo-Nagano-Toyoma-Takayama-Nagoya and then either to Tokyo or Osaka trains only which looks like more scenic

Comment: @AliAwan thats the point of my answer, you can't reserve train tickets outside of JR EAST. As for your second question, it's purely opinion based so I wont answer it here, I did post a comment suggesting a few things however.

Comment: the itinerary i mentioned do i need to make any reservations in advance? or simply buy tickets from the counter

Comment: @AliAwan As my answer mentions, unless you are travelling during a busy period, no you don't need to make reservations. For 2016, Obon will happen between August 6th and 21st. If you do happen to travel at that time, you will most likely need to reserve your tickets in advance.

Comment: @JSLavertu -1 Yes you can? Albeit you have to understand Japanese. https://e5489.jr-odekake.net/e5489/cssp/CBTopMenuSP

Comment: @the wandering coder My answer is oriented towards people who DONT speak Japanese.

Comment: @JSLavertu Which you mentioned nowhere at all, you just said it wasn't possible, which it is. If you want to mention that, then state so in your answer.

Comment: Ill edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @JSLavertu Vote changed accordingly.

Comment: Only some JR East trains can be booked on that service.

Answer (score 8):

You can't buy individual tickets beforehand online.

If you're thinking about getting a JR pass, you need to buy an exchange order from an approved reseller or [travel agency](http://www.japanrailpass.net/en/purchase.html) in your country **before** arriving in Japan and then exchanging it for an actual pass once you arrive.

The pass then becomes your ticket on JR networks (high speed trains and some lines within cities). There's a very informative article on [Japan Guide](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2361.html) about this.

If you don't want to buy a whole pass, you can still buy [individual tickets](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2016.html) but only in Japan. Most stations have machines where you can buy it yourself

Comment: that is  what i was looking for individual tickets to buy online. thanks for your answer

Comment: individual tickets prices are always the same regardless of buying tickets in advance?

Comment: @AliAwan you mean in Japan ? I can't say I had a JR pass, but for the  reservations yes

Comment: my itinerary is Tokyo-Nagano-Toyama-Takayama-Nagoya and then either Osaka or to Tokyo via fujigoko and individual tickets looks more cheaper than 14 day pass

Comment: Sure, but don't forget some trains require reservations

Comment: @AliAwan It may be worth putting your Itinerary in your question.

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Is there any official Japanese website to buy train ticket online?

I assume you're speaking about the Train ticket discount for foreign tourists.

No: http://www.japanrailpass.net/en/purchase.html

> Buy your Exchange Order for the JAPAN RAIL PASS at one of the following sales offices or agents before coming to Japan.
>   JTB Corp., Nippon Travel Agency, KINTETSU INTERNATIONAL, Tobu Top Tours, Japan Airlines, All Nippon Airways, JALPAK, and their associated agencies.

There are websites that sell the JRP, but they are not official outlets.

All the official points of sale are listed in the page linked, divided by geographical region.

Comment: You may want to mention this pass covers only 1 company (JR) and all other smaller and regional companies (as well as bus services) are not covered. Further, this isn't the only pass for foreign tourists nor does the JR Rail Pass cover all services with JR. Also, if you speak Japanese, you can buy Shinkansen tickets directly from the JR West Japanese Website.

Comment: Too bad, your assumption is not correct. -1

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder "JR" is not "one company", and further some non-JR trains as well as some buses are covered as well.

Comment: @fkraiem Apologies, **Group** of Companies. The buses covered are all JR as is the one ferry. The only non-JR lines covered are the Tokyo Monorail between Hamamatsuchō and Haneda Airport and the Aoimori Railway for journeys starting and ending at Hachinohe and Aomori only, and for journeys from these stations to Noheji and the JR East Ōminato Line. Otherwise it is not accepted at any non-JR related company. My comment was merely to say that this answer needs clarification as it merely states "the Train Ticket Discount for tourists" of which there are numerous available for different companies.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder feel free to edit my answer

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder Some new lines have been added when the Hokuriku Shinkansen started operating. ;)

Comment: @fkraiem Does that mean the old lines were discontinued? Or they just got passed on. A JR Pass used to allow you to use the express between Honshu and Hokkaido which has been replaced by the Shinkansen. As I never seem to live here on a Visitor Visa I only have JR sites to go off. 
I know that I missed the The IR Ishikawa Railway Line between Kanazawa and Tsubata. (As long as you don't get off in between). And the Ainokaze Toyama Railway Line between Toyama and Takaoka (Once again without disembarking anywhere except these stations).

Comment: I assume you refer to this? http://www.japanrailpass.net/new_year/JRP_hokkaido_eng_1225.pdf
I still can't see it state any other lines except for JR are valid, in fact it actually sates that some previously accessible lines now are no longer accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I skipped the rail pass since a 2 week pass ended up being more than the journeys we needed. (Tokyo,Kyoto,Odawara,Tokyo)

The JR vending machines take Mastercard so just bought the tickets when needed. FYI the Subway machines didnt accept foreign cards.

If you have time, 1 full day in Hakone was amazing. 
Spent 3 nights in Kyoto, wish we did more.

Comment: yes i have calculated buying individual tickets cost less than pass

Comment: -1 not really an answer to the question.